# JQuery ensure that get requests stay in chronological order

Tags: jquery, get, wait

I need to send several get requests, and i need to make sure that jquery will wait for the request to finnish before moving on to the next requests...

if i simply go

```
$.get("url 1 here", { parameter:"value"}...
$.get("url 2 here", { parameter:"value"}...
$.get("url 3 here", { parameter:"value"}...
```

Will jquery wait for the first request to finnish before it sends the next, or should i do something like:

```
$.get("url 1 here", { parameter:"value"}, function(data){
$.get("url 2 here", { parameter:"value"}, function(data){
$.get("url 3 here", { parameter:"value"});
});
});
```

to ensure that they always finnish before the next is sent? thanks.

Comment: You need to do it the second way.

Comment: The nature of `$.get()` (and all Ajax methods) is that they're not supposed to wait for a response before moving on to whatever the next bit of code is. So yes, the second way.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's ajax methods are asynchronous by default, but it can be changed.
You can do as you described yourself if you want to keep the asynchronous nature (which means the script will continue past your ajax calls), or you can change it to not be asynchronous.

If you want that, you'll have to change from the get to the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'url1',
   async: false,
   data { parameter: 'value' },
   success: function(result) { }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'url2',
   async: false,
   data { parameter: 'value' },
   success: function(result) { }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'url3',
   async: false,
   data { parameter: 'value' },
   success: function(result) { }
});
```

notice here the "async" parameter, which is set to false.

Comment: Please do not EVER recommend setting `async: false`.  This blocks the entire UI as it runs *and* is depreciated and may disappear from new browsers.